# Eclipse inserts a new line in android xml files

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, format

I have an Android xml file which contains something like:

```
    <!-- foto with border -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_border_black"
        android:padding="1dp" >
```

When I remove the blank line between the comment and the LinearLayout and then I do code formatting by <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  or <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> the empty line gets inserted again. I tried to fix this by Settings -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor  by new settings like "Split multiple attributes each on a new line". I had no success.

Answer (score 3):

By default, XML files in Android project will use a custom XML formatter intended for XML files (so it for example has different policies for whether attributes appear on separate lines and blank lines between elements depending on which type of resource file you're editing -- values, layouts, manifests, etc.)

You can edit these preferences under Preferences > Android > Editors.

If you want to use the default XML editor instead (which uses the settings path pointed to by others in this thread) you can also go to that preference page and turn off the custom formatter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using android xml editor check:
Window > Preferences > Android > Editors > Always remove empty lines between elements

Answer (score 0):

set enable

```
Window -> Preference -> XML Files ->Editor ->Clear all blank lines
```

And than use code formatting

Comment: and Format Comment->Join Lines is enabled?

Comment: Yes also with this option enabled or diabled no change.

Answer (score 0):

The Android layout editor has its own formatter.  Perhaps it has its own preference page?